# Customizing the appearance and color of the question in exam class

Tags: exam

How to redefine the colours of questions, and make it appear bold when using `\documentclass{exam}`? I am not looking for a manual solution where I need to edit each and every question myself.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}


\begin{questions}
\question This is question 1
 \begin{solution}
     Solution for question 1
  \end{solution}

\question This is question 2
\(\zeta(z)\) is \(\frac{1}{2}\)

 \question 
  \begin{choices}
   \choice A
   \choice B
  \end{choices}

\question This is question 3
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want every question, but not the solution, to be in bold and in colour?

Comment: Yes, Exactly like that.

Answer (score 3):

`\AtBeginEnvironment{solution}{\color{blue}}` worked for me

Comment: you can add `\textbf` as well if needed

Answer (score 1):

Note this is a manual solution and may not be what you want.

This may be a choice if you just have a few instances to change, using `\usepackage{xcolor}` and for bolded text, you could directly use `\textbf{blah..blah..blah..}`.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}


\begin{questions}
\question \textbf{{\color{blue}This is question 1}}
\begin{solution}
 Solution for question 1
\end{solution}

\question This is question 2
$(\zeta(z))$ is $(\frac{1}{2})$

\question 
\begin{choices}
\choice A
\choice B
\end{choices}

\question This is question 3
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output]

Suppose if you want to do it generally for all the questions, you should probably customize the question environment (that will be handy).

Comment: This solution becomes a manual one. I am not looking for this. Thanks.

Comment: @cosmicraga Could you update the same in your question as well? Because, your question seems more general then.

Comment: This answer is so useless, a manual solution is not a solution at all.

Comment: @JohnD Feel free to give a perfect solution :) no one is stopping you.

Comment: ok, i will do that then

Answer (score 1):

To tweak Question styles, in a pure `exam.cls` way, you can redefine `\questionshook` which may continues to effect on Solution portions too, and this can be compensated with using `SolutionEmphasis` command both in preamble of the document. Thus you need

```
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{1cm}%
      \color{red}\bfseries
}

\SolutionEmphasis{\normalfont\color{black}}
```

You can also play with `\qformat`, `\partshook`, `\subpartshook`, `\subsubpartshook`, `\choiceshook`.

[Relatable Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180992/using-extrawidth-in-exam-class-results-in-unwanted-margin-changes-per-page)

Comment: Is there any way to color only part labels?